# Akka actors are getting stopped

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor, timeoutexception

I'm using akka actors to achieve parallel processing of some http requests. I've initailized a pool of actors using `RoundRobinPool` like:

```
ActorRef myActorPool = actorSystem.actorOf(new RoundRobinPool(200).props(Props.create(MyActor.class, args)), MyActor.class.getSimpleName());
```

It is working fine. But after the process is running for sometime, i'm getting following error

> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://web_server/user/MyActor#-769383443]] had already been terminated. Sender[null] sent the message of type "com.data.model.Request".

So I've overridden `postStop` method added a log statement there.

```
@Override
public void postStop() {
    log.warn("Actor is stopped");
}
```

Now, I can see in the logs that the actors are getting stopped. But I'm not sure for which request it is happening. Once all the actors in the pool terminates (200 is the pool size I've set), I'm getting `AskTimeoutException` as said before. Is there anyway to debug why the actors are getting terminated?

**EDIT 1**

In the controller, I'm using the created actor pool like

```
CompletableFuture<Object> s = ask(myActorPool, request, 1000000000).toCompletableFuture();
return s.join();
```

The actor processes one kind of messages only.

```
@Override
public AbstractActor.Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
            .match(Request.class, this::process)
            .build();
}

private void process(Request request) {
    try {
        // code here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        getSender().tell(new akka.actor.Status.Failure(e), getSelf());
    }
}
```

Comment: if you can add the code snipt that would be helpful.

Comment: This is how are you creating the actors. How are you actually using the actors?

Comment: Looking at the code looks like you are only sending response to the sender only when there is an exception (in the catch block). You need to send the response in `try` block as well.

Comment: I haven't added the code in `try` block but it actually sends response to sender.

Comment: I don't know if it is related with this issue but you are blocking threads on `s.join()`. Depending on your project settings/framework you could run out of available threads so the entire app could be sluggish so the timeouts.

Answer (score -2):

As far as you have described the probelm it seems you are processing your data inside the ask call and taking more time than askTimeout, and you are getting the error.

What you can do is either increase the askTimeout or do less processing inside tha ask call.

you should not do CPU bound operations inside the ask call, it can cause slowing down your system it is recommended that you should do the I/O bound operations inside the ask call. That way you can leverage the actors.

For example:

```
val x=x+1   // CPU bound operation should not do inside the ask call
```

some db call you can do inside the ask call that is preferable.

Comment: I've edited my answer. the default timeout is very high (1000000000). Even though i'm getting response in 10-20 secs, I can see in the logs that actors are getting stopped.

Comment: Default ask timeout is 10s as i know and you are getting reponse really slow becasue 10 to 20 sec is too much to do the back end processing.

Comment: But the timeout I've mentioned in the ask call is much greater than 10s, right. And also the operations I'm doing in the method are not CPU bound. Most operations are database related queries only.

Comment: Are you updating some mutable variables?? Inside ask?